# Count Parents tag in JSON file iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

Actually I am going to make a project where some Emoticons will show in some `UIView` & user first have to download those files (image & JSON) from server. This is my `JSON` file: (it is not fixed, may be more Parents tag `"Frames"`, will add in future)

```
{
    "Frames1":
    [{"Image":"smiley64_1_1.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_2.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_3.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_4.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_5.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_6.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_7.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_8.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_9.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_10.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_11.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_12.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_13.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_14.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_15.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_16.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_17.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_18.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_19.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_1_20.png", "Time":"0.04"}],

    "Frames2":
    [{"Image":"smiley64_2_1.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_2.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_3.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_4.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_5.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_6.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_7.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_8.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_9.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_10.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_11.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_12.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_13.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_14.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_15.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_16.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_17.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_18.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_19.png", "Time":"0.04"},
     {"Image":"smiley64_2_20.png", "Time":"0.04"}]
}
```

Here for `"Frames1"` parents tag, I'm getting `Image` & `Time` child key's value separately and put them in two separate `NSMUtableArray` which are `imageNamesArray` & `durationArray`.

```
-(void) retriveData
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"smiley64" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *content = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:content options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    //this is your loop array
    NSArray *objArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Frames1"];
    NSLog(@"COUNT %@", objArray);

    self.imageNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.durationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dic in objArray)
    {
        [self.imageNamesArray addObject:dic[@"Image"]];
        [self.durationArray addObject:dic[@"Time"]];
    }
}
```

**Out put:**
**imageNamesArray:** smiley64_1_1.png, smiley64_1_2.png,....smiley64_1_20.png

**durationArray:** 0.04, 0.04,...........0.04

Now what I want is to count the **"Parents tag"** (`Frames`). With it I will show every Parent's child tag which are images and their timeDuration in separated `UIImageView` as Emoticons.

Something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    NSString *Parents = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Frames%i", i];
    NSLog(@"hola %@", Parents);

    //this is your loop array
    //NSArray *objArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Frames1"];
    NSArray *objArray = [dictionary objectForKey:Parents];
    //NSLog(@"COUNT %@", objArray);

    self.imageNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.durationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dic in objArray)
    {
        [self.imageNamesArray addObject:dic[@"Image"]];
        [self.durationArray addObject:dic[@"Time"]];
    }

    NSLog(@"imageNamesArray %@", self.imageNamesArray);
    NSLog(@"durationArray %@", self.durationArray);
}
```

But I don't know how to count, the number of parents tag like `Frames` in my `JSON`?
If any thing want to know please ask me. Any kind of help will must be appreciated. A lot of thanks in advance.

Full Code:

```
/*--------------------- Retrive the data from JSON (Down) ---------------------*/
-(void) retriveData
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"smiley64" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *content = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:content options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        NSString *Parents = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Frames%i", i];
        NSLog(@"hola %@", Parents);

        //this is your loop array
        //NSArray *objArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Frames1"];
        NSArray *objArray = [dictionary objectForKey:Parents];
        //NSLog(@"COUNT %@", objArray);

        self.imageNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.durationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSDictionary *dic in objArray)
        {
            [self.imageNamesArray addObject:dic[@"Image"]];
            [self.durationArray addObject:dic[@"Time"]];
        }

        NSLog(@"imageNamesArray %@", self.imageNamesArray);
        NSLog(@"durationArray %@", self.durationArray);
    }

}
/*--------------------- Retrive the data from JSON (Up) ---------------------*/


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self retriveData];

    count = 0;
    [self imageAnimation];
}


/*--------------------- Perform the sequence animation (Down) ---------------------*/
-(void) imageAnimation
{
    if (count == imageNamesArray.count)
    {
        count = 0;
        [self imageAnimation];
    }
    else
    {
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageNamesArray objectAtIndex:count]];
        [self performSelector:@selector(imageAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:[[self.durationArray objectAtIndex:count] doubleValue]];
        count++;
    }
}
/*--------------------- Perform the sequence animation (Up) ---------------------*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDictionary has method `allKeys`

```
NSArray *allKeys = [dictionary allKeys];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < allKeys.count; i ++) {
     NSArray *imagesArray = [dictionary objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:i]];
     //parse your images
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but I am searching about the way of counting `Parents` Tag. Not their Key or Value.

Comment: [allKeys count] - this is answer for your question. This allow to count amount of keys in dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

To count only the keys of your json-object, that are named "Frames..." you can use this method:

```
 //The dictionary parameter should be your dictionary from your NSJSONSerialization
-(NSInteger)countFramesKeysFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary{
    NSInteger framesCounter = 0;
    for (id key in [dictionary allKeys]) {
        NSString *keyAsString = (NSString *) key;
        if ([keyAsString containsString:@"Frames"]) {
            framesCounter++;
        }
    }
    return framesCounter;
}
```

If all keys on the highest level in your json-dictionary are named "Frames..", like it is in your example above you can use

```
[[dictionary allKeys] count];
```

like Pavel Gatilov mentioned before.